# \tcolorbox: footnote on page on which there are

Tags: footnotes, boxes, tcolorbox

I use in my document [boxes created](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124233/nonstandard-quotation-margins) with [tcolorbox](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox) package. Each box can cover few pages in document, and I would like to add some footnotes inside the box. But I want the footnotes to occur together with the standard footnotes in my document, so I use [\footnotemark](http://www.forkosh.com/latex/ltx-232.html) inside the box. But there is a problem. Each footnote should occur at the bottom of the page on which it appears, not after box.

Do you have any suggestions?

I've found [this topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6069/conditioning-footnotes-on-where-the-footnotemark-is-in-the-page), but it didn't help me.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,changepage}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=2cm,right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{myquotation}{%
  blank,breakable,parbox=false,check odd page,left=2cm,
  toggle left and right}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4]

\begin{myquotation}
\lipsum[1-5]
\textbf{And here I would like to add first footnote\footnotemark. At the bottom of this page.}
\lipsum[1-5]
\textbf{And after some text, here should be second footnote\footnotemark. At the bottom of this page.}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{myquotation}

\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}\footnotetext{first footnote}
\addtocounter{footnote}{1}\footnotetext{second footnote}

\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Currently, I see no solution for that wish. The footnotes _are_ placed correctly, but not at the place you want them to be. To do the trick, the footnotes had to be transported outside the box while breaking the page which would heavily interfere with the break algorithm. I'm sorry.

Comment: [Alternatives to footnotes?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33910) might be useful- see the comment that quotes Jill Knuth :)

Comment: @mc2 was your problem solved then? if so, please provide an answer for your question to remove it from the list of unanswered questions

Comment: @masu Unfortunately problem is not solved. I've decided to not use footnotes in that way.

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm: Can this problem be solved with a newer version of `tcolorbox` 'now'?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Sorry for the delay (I am offline on Christmas holiday). No, there is no change regarding footnotes. And I do not see a way to do this...

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm: Thanks for reply. Well, what to do with this question then. Closing because it's impossible?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I do not expect an answer which could fulfill the requirements. So, maybe, this question should be closed. It could be reopened or asked again if new things are showing up.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer But none of the closing options are really correct ... Something like 'cannot be done' is missing from the option list.

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm: Perhaps 'off-topic' as it requests a feature that is not yet possible with LaTeX (or even `expl3`)?

Comment: Currently, there seems to be no way to achieve the requirements.

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm: By the way: I think there will be a free TUG - membership competition in some days starting. I **expect**  (;-)) you to nominate yourself again -- a year ago you stepped down to give Sean Allred the win.

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm You said (a long time ago) “Currently, there seems to be no way to achieve the requirements”. But isn't [this method provided by John Kormylo](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/611437/18401) precisely a way to achieve the requirements?